# Connection to server in Docker container on localhost very slow

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wanted to try Docker as a tool for local development — I used `docker-compose` to spin up 3 containers: one for the database (postgres), front-end (running webpack and node sass in watch mode) and backend (Elixir/Phoenix).

Everything works great, except that when I hit `localhost:4000` the page load is really slow — 10-15 seconds just to get the login page, which is static.

I checked the logs from `docker-compose` and the server response times are fast as usual, which to me it means that something is slowing down the connection to the container.

When I ran the server directly in the Terminal again, everything is pretty fast, e.g. takes 1s to load the same page.

I'm new to Docker so I suspect I might be missing something configuration-wise. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

**Configuration**

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  front-end:
    container_name: front-end
    env_file:
      - "docker/dev/.env"
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/dev/Dockerfile.front-end"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - static:/app/priv/static
    command: npm run dev

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/dev/Dockerfile.backend"
    env_file:
      - "docker/dev/.env"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - front-end
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - elixir-deps:/app/deps
      - static:/app/priv/static
    command: iex -S mix phx.server

volumes:
  postgres:
  elixir-deps:
  node_modules:
  static:
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: "tmpfs"
```

*Dockerfile.front-end*

```
FROM node:8.10-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

*Dockerfile.backend*

```
FROM elixir:1.8-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base inotify-tools postgresql-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY mix.exs ./
COPY mix.lock ./

RUN mix local.hex --force && mix local.rebar --force \
    && mix deps.get && mix deps.compile

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000
```

**Versions & other info:**

```
MacOS Mojave 10.14.3
Docker Desktop 2.0.0.3 (Engine 18.09.2, Compose: 1.23.2)

MacBook Pro 13" (Early 2015, 16GB RAM/3.1GHz Core i7)
```

Comment: How much RAM and how many CPUs have you provided to Docker and how much are the containers using?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I'm guessing I'm currently using whatever default there are in place — I haven't change anything myself. How can I check and increase the resources allocated?

Comment: [`docker system info`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_info/) gives you an overview of the current settings.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Thank you! Looks like it has 2 CPUs and nearly 2GB of RAM. I ran `docker stats --all` and RAM usage is fairly low (~300MB); CPU usage overall seems to spike to 60-80% on a request, otherwise it's very low too. To me it seems that resources are fine as they are, but I'm not sure — what do you think?

Comment: Can you add the details necessary to reproduce this _to the question itself_, not behind a link?  Note that [`docker run -v` on a Mac is known to be slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap), and if you're trying to import your entire application through a bind mount, either building it into an image or using a tool like Homebrew to install a language runtime without Docker will be faster.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sure, I've added the config files to the question. Thanks for the link, I'll have a read and let you know if this answers my question.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks again for the link. I'm not sure what to make of it though, does it imply there is no solution? Or is there some kind of way to use caching to improve performance as a workaround? I'm a bit lost so if you could provide an example, I'll greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 5 June 2020:**

It is significantly better to use [`docker-sync`](https://docker-sync.io/) for local development.

First make sure you `down` existing services to remove old volumes.

Then create a `docker-sync.yml` like so:

```
version: "2"
options:
  # Renamed compose file to `docker-compose.dev.yml`
  compose-dev-file-path: 'docker-compose.dev.yml'

syncs:
  # This name should be unique and should not clash with
  # an existing container or service name. You can use it
  # as a volume in docker compose yml.
  project:
    src: '.'
    sync_excludes: ['node_modules', 'deps', '_build']
```

Now you can use the `project` volume instead of `- .:/app` for `front-end` and `backend` services, e.g.

```
    volumes:
      - project:/app:nocopy
      - elixir-deps:/app/deps
      - elixir-build:/app/_build
      - static:/app/priv/static:ro
```

Run `docker-sync start` to start it in the background, followed by running `docker-compose up --build --detach` as usual.

**Original answer:**

As one commenter pointed out ([@DavidMaze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze)), there are currently [known performance issues](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap) with Docker for Mac. How much are they linked to my use case I cannot tell, but after reading the [Performance tuning guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/) in the official docs, I managed to make some progress in performance:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  front-end:
    container_name: front-end
    env_file:
      - "docker/dev/.env"
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/dev/Dockerfile.front-end"
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - static:/app/priv/static
    command: npm run dev

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/dev/Dockerfile.backend"
    env_file:
      - "docker/dev/.env"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - front-end
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
      - elixir-deps:/app/deps
      - elixir-build:/app/_build
      - static:/app/priv/static:ro
    command: iex -S mix phx.server

volumes:
  postgres:
  elixir-deps:
  elixir-build:
  node_modules:
  static:
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: "tmpfs"
```

Note the use of `:delegated` when declaring the `.:/app:delegated` volumes.

Although this is an improvement, it is still much slower for day-to-day development than running things natively, so I'm welcoming other answers to my question. For the time being, I think that's probably the best solution.

Comment: Thx, man! Your advice boosted up my app loading from 4-8 sec to 600ms-1s!

Comment: @AlexanderZnaydyuk I'm glad this helped. Hopefully one day performance on MacOS will be as good as on Windows/Linux.

Comment: I'm having this same problem on Windows, it takes around 60s to execute queries from my guest Apache server to a remote database. Do you have to make the whole installation procedure for docker-sync or just the command :delegated will do the trick?

Comment: @KevinGaray Are you sure that it is not a networking issue ? Your services should be on the same network. You should try `network_mode: bridge` or define your own network. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/